# Learn Python The Hard Way Exercise 21 Extra Credit

Tags: python

I am not following the part below in exercise 21, I guess because I am weak in Maths.

```
# A puzzle for the extra credit, type it in anyway.

print "Here is a puzzle."

what = add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, divide(iq, 2))))

print "That becomes: ", what, "Can you do it by hand?"
```

> **Description:**
>
> At the end of the script is a puzzle. I'm taking the return value of
>   one function and using it as the argument of another function. I'm
>   doing this in a chain so that I'm kind of creating a formula using the
>   functions. It looks really weird, but if you run the script you can
>   see the results. What you should do is try to figure out the normal
>   formula that would recreate this same set of operations.

My question is what is the normal formula, and how did you work it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line of code:

```
what = add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, divide(iq, 2))))
```

translates to:

```
age + (height - (weight * (iq / 2)))
```

which can be simplified, due to order of operations, to:

```
age + height - weight * iq / 2
```

or in English:

```
Age plus Height subtract Weight times half of IQ
```

---

The way I worked it out was to expand the statement out a little bit so it is easier to read:

**Step 1:**

```
add(
    age, subtract(
        height, multiply(
            weight, divide(
                iq, 2
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Then translate each statement starting from the inner-most statement:

**Step 2:**

```
add(
    age, subtract(
        height, multiply(
            weight, (iq / 2)
        )
    )
)
```

**Step 3:**

```
add(
    age, subtract(
        height, (weight * (iq / 2))
    )
)
```

**Step 4:**

```
add(
    age, (height - (weight * (iq / 2)))
)
```

**Step 5:**

```
age + (height - (weight * (iq / 2)))
```

**EDIT:**

You need a base level of understanding that:

```
multiply(x, y) is equivalent to x * y
add(x, y) is equivalent to x + y
subtract(x, y) is equivalent to x - y
divide(x, y) is equivalent to x / y
```

Then you need to also understand that these can be combined:

```
multiply(x, add(y, z)) is equivalent to multiply(x, (y + z)), and  x * (y + z)
```

I put the brackets around `(y + z)` to show that it should be calculated first, because the inner values are always calculated first in the embedded functions.

Comment: Where does it start from? In other words, what is the order of operation?

Comment: Calculated multiplication and division left to right, then perform addition/subtraction left to right

Comment: But in your original statement it will execute the inner-most methods first. In this case `div(iq, 2)` or `iq / 2`

Comment: Do you understand that `multiply(x, y)` is the same as `x * y`? And as an extension of that, `multiply(x, add(y, z))` is the same as `x * (y + z)`?

Comment: No I do not understand. I was bad in Algebra in school.

Comment: See my Edit down the bottom of my answer

Answer (score 1):

The "normal formula" is:
    age + (height - (weight * (iq / 2)))

As for why, start with your code:

```
add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, divide(iq, 2))))
```

This code will execute `divide(iq, 2)` first, giving us (iq/2). To visualize, I'll replace the function with its "normal" result:

```
add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, (iq/2))))
```

With that value, `multiply(weight, (iq/2))` can be calculated. So `weight` and `iq/2` are multiplied--`weight*(iq/2)`. Again, replacing the function with the "normal" result:

```
add(age, subtract(height, (weight*(iq/2)))
```

Now `subtract(height, (weight*(iq/2))) is calculated, subtracting the 2nd argument from the first one:

```
add(age, (height - (weight * (iq/2))))
```

Finally, `add()` is evaluated and adds `age` to the rest of the equation, so your final "normal" result is:

```
age + height - (weight * iq/2)
```